# how to turn off Salesforce local source track tracking in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce-development

Somehow I have managed to 'accidentally' turn on Salesforce Local Source Tracking (but, I am not using scratch orgs).  It is creating new files every time I switch branches (I use github) and make any changes.  Is there a way this can be turned off or disabled?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried deleting the .sf and .sfdx and executed `sfdx force:source:push` but that obviously was not the right thing to do. I have also tried adding and removing the 'Access Salesforce DX (for Developers only)' permission set from my user.  The DevOps Center is disabled in my org.  It has never been enabled.

[image: Screenshot of VSCode files that continue to be created]

Answer (score 0):

Add .sf to git ignore file to ignore those changes.

```
#ignore .sf logs
.sf
```